# Xcode using wrong localization

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have two localizations in my project: Base (which is in English) and Swedish. When I set my phone to Swedish it works, and when I set it to English it works. But when I set it to another language, for example German, it uses the Swedish translations instead of Base. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found the answer. In the phones settings, you don't just set the current language, you set language priorities. So if you've had Swedish and switches to another language, Swedish will be second priority and English lower.

Answer (score 2):

Go to your target and then to the Info tab. Under "Custom iOS Target Properties" you will find an entry with the name "Localization native development region". This entry determines which is the default language, the one displayed in case that there in no localization resource for the selected language. Make sure that the entry is set to "en".

Comment: It is set to en. Is it possible to reset all localization settings and start over? Maybe something went wrong when I first added localization to the project.

Comment: When you go to your project and then to Info, you can set the languages that you use and also select whether you use base internationalization. I suppose, you can use them to reset the settings. However, make sure that you store/copy somewhere your project before that. It is very probable that its `lproj` folders (e.g. `en.lproj`) get deleted. In case that you have localized storyboards, that may bring you a lot of work. And, basically, all that you want is to put the content of the english folder in the main folder of the project and to remove the other lproj folders.

Comment: I have only localized localizable.strings, not the storyboard. In the project folder there's Base.lproj and sv.lproj. When I deleted the Swedish localization from the project the phone started using the Base (English) translations, but as soon as I added Swedish again it switched to that. Both language and region is set to German/Germany.

Comment: Have you tried cleaning and building again? If that does not help, have a look at this tutorial: http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-tutorial-localization-apps/. Maybe you will get some more ideas about what could be wrong in your project settings. Without the project in front of me, it is quite difficult to know what went wrong.

Comment: Yes, I have cleaned, and cleaned build folder. I even tried creating a whole new project, copying over all files except the localization files, and localize again. Same problem. Base is ignored when I add Swedish.